# importing issue: DateFormat on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to getting my current date time on my application but suddenly, the method "DateFormat" is not syncing on my application, even I was added the import library at the top.Also if you hover upon the error "DateFormat", it is placing a creation of new class.. since it is not recognizable on my application.

here is my codes:

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl_browser.dart';


class LabelTextID extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    String formatted = formatter.format(now);
    return  Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 130,
              height: 40.0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Text(
                  "ID",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 26.0, color: Colors.black54),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 40.0,
                decoration:new BoxDecoration(
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "12",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 26.0, color: Colors.black54),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

see also this picture attached upon error.

[image]

Comment: did you make sure that you add package in your pubspec.yaml file and run flutter pub get?

Comment: sorry I'm newbie in this filed, and yes, I didn't  add the package on my dependencies.. its working now.. thanks guys..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `DateFormat`,you should use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Dont forget to add `intl: ^0.16.1` in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: not working on me, does not showing intellisense for "package:intl**** "

Comment: make sure you add `intl: ^0.16.1` in `pubspec.yaml`.